# Disk space Confusion!

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage, storage

Recently every time i log in i am greeted with this:
The filesystem Root has 0 bytes left.
So i check `df -H` and this is what it looks like:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           355M   15M  341M   5% /run
/dev/sda5       9.3G  8.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.8G  1.6M  1.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       536M  3.8M  533M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           355M   37k  355M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1        17G  8.2k   17G   1% /media/bossbmm/BOI
/dev/sda4       1.1M   18k  937k   2% /media/bossbmm/ed64f534-9a8c-4f77-95ce-e740c62f0eb7
```

And says i have no storage left and i cant do anything i have deleted everything in my home directory plz help.

Comment: Your root partition on /dev/sda5 is too small (and it's full). Post a screenshot of gparted view of sda, and we'll try and make a recommendation. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the trash: `/home/*/.local/share/Trash`

And next time you should remove files/directories by: `rm -fr FILE`, then it will be remove immediately instant of moving first to trash.

You can also check: `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /`.